# How to group test data in a parameterized test?

Tags: java, junit4, parameterized-unit-test

I'm working on an application which has a grid and only some points of the grid are considered valid. I need to test this extensively with all possible grid values or at least with all the boundary points.

I've tried out parameterized tests. It works fine expect for the fact that the data becomes unmanageable after a point. Sample test for a 3x3 grid is given below.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class GridGameTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { 0, 0, false }, { 0, 1, false }, { 0, 2, false }, 
                { 1, 0, false }, { 1, 1, true }, { 1, 2, false },
                { 2, 0, false }, { 2, 1, false }, { 2, 2, false }
                                 } );
    }

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final boolean isValid;

    public GridGameTest(int x, int y, boolean isValid){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }

    @Test
    public void testParameterizedInput(){
        Grid grid = new Grid(3,3);
        assertEquals(isValid, grid.isPointValid(new Point(x,y)));
    }
}
```

Any inputs on how to group/manage the data, so that my test remains simple and readable??

Answer (score 1):

I would create a data generator instead of having to hardcode all possible values. Something like:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
    Object[][] result = new Object[3][3];
    for (Boolean flag : new Boolean[]{Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE})
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
          Object[] row = new Object[] {j, i, flag};
          result[i][j] = row;
        }
      }
    }
    return Arrays.asList(result);
}
```

Failed tests are anyway printing parameters.

Comment: With the data generator, I wont get the kind of input that I've given in my example. This would give me two arrays with all x and y values with true and false. I'm expecting only the middle point to be true. Rest of them should be false.

Answer (score 1):

i would separate tests into 2 groups. valid and invalid points. if there is really many points then use `@Parameterized` to generate them instead of listing them. or use JunitParams to read them from file. if you prefer to keep all the points in the source file then i suggest using [zohhak](http://zohhak.googlecode.com):

```java
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.Coercion;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.TestWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.runners.ZohhakRunner;

@RunWith(ZohhakRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    Grid grid = new Grid(3,3);

    @TestWith({
        "1-1"
    })
    public void should_be_valid_point(Point point) {
        assertTrue(grid.isPointValid(point));
    }

    @TestWith({
        "0-0",
        "1-0",
        "2-0",
        "2-1"
    })
    public void should_be_invalid_point(Point point) {
        assertFalse(grid.isPointValid(point));
    }

    @Coercion
    public Point parsePoint(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split("-");
        return new Point(parseInt(split[0]), parseInt(split[1]));
    }
}
```